# Number of possible permutations for N groups from I items where each item is of a different size but group total is fixed across groups

Tags: permutation

this is my first post.

I am not sure how to approach this problem, I would like direction or even an algebraic  solution please.

I have to sort 70 different sized items out into 12 groups.
Each group has the same total allowed size, the size has minimum and maximum.

I want to know how to work out the total possible permutations there are? How would I go about working this out?

Thanks

Comment: This is probably more an optimization than a stats/ML topic. Depending on your specific problem, you may have quite a large number of possible groupings, up to $12^{70}=3.5\times 10^{75}$.

Comment: thanks for the answer @StephanKolassa, I feel dumb should have know that but my math's is rusty and I was over complicating doh yes you're right my bad.